# Pull data using only associated key in mongodb and php

Tags: php, mongodb

How to pull inner array having key `address1`

```
"_id": 2,
"info": {
    "address1": {
        "city": {
            "0": "Indore"
        },
        "state": {
            "0": "MP"
        }
    },
    "address2": {
        "city": {
            "0": "Mhow"
        },
        "state": {
            "0": "MP"
        }
    }
}
```

After removing data should be :

```
"_id": 2,
"info": {
    "address1": {
        "city": {
            "0": "Indore"
        },
        "state": {
            "0": "MP"
        }
    }
}
```

I used this `db.info.update({"_id":2},{'$pull':{"info":{"address1":{'$exists':true}}}})`
But It gives error `Cannot apply $pull/$pullAll modifier to non-array`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the mongo console:

```
> db.tester.find()
{ "_id" : 2, "info" : { "address1" : { "city" : { "0" : "Indore" }, "state" : { "0" : "MP" } }, "address2" : { "city" : { "0" : "Mhow" }, "state" : { "0" : "MP" } } } }
> db.tester.findAndModify({query: {"_id":2}, update : {$unset: {"info.address2":1}}, new:true})
{
    "_id" : 2,
    "info" : {
        "address1" : {
            "city" : {
                "0" : "Indore"
            },
            "state" : {
                "0" : "MP"
            }
        }
    }
}
> db.tester.find()
{ "_id" : 2, "info" : { "address1" : { "city" : { "0" : "Indore" }, "state" : { "0" : "MP" } } } }
```

Does this accomplish what you need?

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me like what you really want is an array of addresses, right? So you users can have unlimited addresses? If so, you should have an array, like this:

```
"_id": 2,
"info": {
    "address": [{
        "city": {
            "0": "Indore"
        },
        "state": {
            "0": "MP"
        }
    },
     {
        "city": {
            "0": "Mhow"
        },
        "state": {
            "0": "MP"
        }
    }]
}
```

With address now as an array you can use $push and $pull

Comment: This is a much better system for the OP to use, sometimes changing the problem is better than finding a solution(especially when it's pretty ugly like mine).  +1